# WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested in jboss , Not able to start?

Tags: jboss7.x

[image]

Jboss Not able to start ! Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have deleted `data` directory. The error clearly says :

> To correct the problem, either restart with the --admin-only switch set and use the CLI to install the missing content or remove it from the configuration, or remove the deployment from the xml configuration file and restart.